# (error) ERR unknown command `PROXY` with Redis besind Traefik

Tags: kubernetes, redis, traefik

I try to use a redis besind a traefik proxy, but i have the error : ERR unknown command `PROXY`.

I try this:

```
.\redis-cli.exe -h my-traefik-ip -p 443
my-traefik-ip :443> PING
(error) ERR unknown command `PROXY`, with args beginning with: `TCP4`, `ip1`, `ip2`, `50076`, `8443`, 
my-traefik-ip :443> PING
PONG
my-traefik-ip :443> FluSHALL
PONG
my-traefik-ip :443> PING
OK
```

The redis response seems on bad order.

This is my K8S config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis

  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:     
        - name: redis
          image: redistimeseries:1.4.10
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 101          
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
          resources:  
            requests:
              cpu: 0.3
              memory: 2000Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 0.5
              memory: 3000Mi
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /data
            name: redis
      volumes:
      - name: redis
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-gluster-redis          
          #args:
          #- --requirepass
          #- "test"  
       
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
    name: redis
  selector:
    app: redis

---

apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: middle-redis-service
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes: 
      - /redis-service

---

apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
  name: ingress-redis-service
spec:
  entryPoints:                  # [1]
    - websecure
  routes:                       # [2]
  - match: HostSNI(`*`)         # [3]
    priority: 10                # [4]
    middlewares:
    - name: middle-redis-service        # [5]
      namespace: default        # [6]
    services:                   # [7]
    - name: redis-service                 # [8]
      port: 6379               # [9]
      weight: 10                # [10]
      terminationDelay: 400     # [11]
      proxyProtocol:            # [12]
        version: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue, but with Nginx Ingress Controller.

Solution was to change type of Service to LoadBalancer. As I was using EKS in AWS, that created Classic Load Balancer resource in AWS and I was able to access redis without any issues using Load Balancer address